# Is the Minimax's evaluation function an Heuristic function?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, heuristics

Is the Minimax's evaluation function an Heuristic function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minimax is an algorithm to determine best next move according to an estimation of a given state.
**In the vast majority of cases, it really is an estimation** (heuristic) but that's not **always** the case (e.g. when you give score to a "win" situation - you give it infinity, and you can really say that's what it's worth).  Maybe one can argue that's an estimation as well.. But you get the point (-:
Anyhow **you can use Minimax either if you estimate, or if you know exactly what's the score of the given states**.

Answer (score 0):

Minimax is a rather **deterministic** algorithm which relies on potentially **heuristic** evaluations to decide what the next move is. In that sense I wouldn't say it is heuristic, because it will **always** choose the best possible move.